# How to lazy load images in angular if data-src attributed is added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, image

How to lazy load images in angular app if image's `data-src` attributed is added dynamically?
For instance application first process html document and strip off all `src` attribute from images and replace them with `data-src`.
Then html document inserted into view, but no lazy loading happens.